# Update dictionary with key only when id exists in array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update my dictionary based on a value existing in an array, that also exists as a value between key-value pairs. However, I find that once the value matches and I update the dictionary with an extra key, all other values afterwards are also updated. I tried to delete them if they appear after, but it deletes it for all.

For example:

```
const dd = {
    somedata : 'hello',
    anotherset: 'bye',
    data : {
        udo: {
            id: 123456789
        }
    }
}

const someId = [987, 654, 123, 567]

const arr = [123, 456]

const someFunc = (arr) => {
    for(const id of someId){
        dd.data.udo.customer_id = id;
        //c
        for(const a of arr){
            if(a === dd.data.udo.customer_id){
                dd.data.udo.test = 'test_account';
                
            } else {
                if('test_account' === dd.data.udo.test){
                    delete dd.data.udo.test;
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(dd));
                continue
            }
        }
    } 
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(someFunc(arr)));
```

Produces the following:

```
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":987}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":987}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":654}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":654}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":123}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":567}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":567}}}
```

I expect something like:

```
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":987}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":987}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":654}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":654}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":123,"test":"test_account"}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":567}}}
{"somedata":"hello","anotherset":"bye","data":{"udo":{"id":123456789,"customer_id":567}}}
```

Comment: the `console.log(JSON.stringify(dd));` is inside the `else` so it will never log the "test_account". try to put it outside (after) the `else`

Comment: Also, `someFunc` doesn't return any value so the last line makes no sense, you could just call ` someFunc(arr)` and it would be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```js
const dd = {
  somedata: 'hello',
  anotherset: 'bye',
  data: {
    udo: {
      id: 123456789
    }
  }
}

const someId = [987, 654, 123, 567]

const arr = [123, 456]

const someFunc = (arr) => {
  for (const id of someId) {
    dd.data.udo.customer_id = id;
    for (const a of arr) {
      if (a === id) {
        dd.data.udo.test = 'test_account';
      } else {
        if ('test_account' === dd.data.udo.test && a !== id) {
          delete dd.data.udo.test;
          continue;
        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dd));
    }
  }
}
someFunc(arr);
```